# Microsoft Excel formula not working properly

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016, formatting

I want to format a cell which is greater than 365 value. The problem is I put the formula of datedif(a1,b1,"d")&" "&"Days" and the result in the cell is 390. I want this to be red because it is greater than 365. I can format it if I only use datedif(a1,b1,"d") without & Functions; please help
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdEWN.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I done to make this work:

[image]

- Select `C2:C4`:
- Use conditional formatting formula:

  ```
  =DATEDIF($A2,$B2,"d")>365
  ```

If you need this to be equal or higher then 365, then just change to `>=`.

---

A much better alternative (IMHO) is to keep your original formula in `C2:C4` without the "days" part (`=DATEDIF($A2,$B2,"d"`), but change the formatting of these cells to a custom format:

```
0 "days"
```

Now you can simply add a conditional formatting of values higher then 365, **AND** you can do calculations with your cells since they simply still numbers looking like text instead of actual text.

[image]

See how the allignment is different too!

Comment: Thank you IMHO works like a charm

Comment: @AlySheikh, IMHO = In My Honest Oppinion, meaning I feel that the 2nd option is better =), but that asside I'm glad it worked. Feel free to accept the answer by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.

Comment: haha =)) i did not know that